# html5 web app - redirect on desktop

Tags: html, media

I built a mobile app with html5. Upon being visited on a desktop, I would like the app to redirect to a page prompting the user to download the app on their phone/tablet. 
How should I go about this? media queries? if so, what would be the right syntax?

Thank you!

annie

Answer (score 0):

I could give you an answer, but I feel that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery) describes in much more detail the pros and cons of many different avenues of approach.

I think javascript would be the best way of doing it. But I believe similar libraries are available in PHP. Also, CSS has a couple of ways of linking to style sheets for mobile only devices. This could be used to display or hide a `<div>` element containing information about downloading, or even a qr code.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have perused them quite systematically and think I am getting close. The alternate css version would be too convoluted, as I want a completely different content for the desktop version.I have tried                                            <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (min-width:1224px)" href="nophone.html"/>                                              but the page doesn't seem to redirect to the nophone.html url...

Comment: That's not even close. You can't use the link tag or html files. You'd have to use javascript like suggested in the other thread.